# Spring's dispatcher servlet requestmapping issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have an issue where I'm trying to link a page to another.

Some of the pages link successfully because I have @RequestMapping annotations on them that return a String object for the view name like so:

```
@RequestMapping("/page1")
public String showMessage(Model model, HttpServletRequest req)
{
    Accessor ac = new Accessor();
    ac.setDate(new Date());
    ac.setIP(req.getRemoteAddr());
    ac.setLocalname(req.getRemoteHost());
    hibernateExcerptSpitter.addAccessor(ac);
    List<Excerpt> list = hibernateExcerptSpitter.retrieveAll();
    model.addAttribute("SOMELIST", list);
    return "page1";
        }
```

but for some others like "register.jsp" for example, where I don't have RequestMapping annotations don't load when I try to link them.

My question is, is it possible to load these pages without having RequestMapping and identifying the view name to return or do I explicitly require to put @RequestMapping and return the view name as a String on each page that I want rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `@RequestMapping` for every url that the user can open. Spring MVC offers a bit of flexibility. You could, e.g., do something like

```
@RequestMapping("/bla/{page}")
public String showPage(@PathVariable String page) {
  return page;
}
```

Usually you need different actions and models for your pages. So I don't see the problem with having an `@RequestMapping` for every page.